# CSS Centered Width Styling in Vaadin Theme - Java

Tags: java, html, css, spring, vaadin

I have a weird behavior that I can not explain to myself. Could anyone explain this to me?

I would like to have a Horizontal Layout of width:80% and it contains buttons and they should be also centered. But It comes out weird. I decided to include the HTML code with .css - Let me know if you need the Java/Vaadin code as well. But I think that .CSS should dictate everything here.

```
import com.vaadin.flow.component.Component;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.HorizontalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;

@Route("")
public class TestView extends VerticalLayout {

    public TestView() {
        Button test = new Button("Test");
        test.setWidth("30%");
        Button test1 = new Button("Test");
        test1.setWidth("30%");
        Button test2 = new Button("Test");
        test2.setWidth("30%");
        
        HorizontalLayout horizontalLayout = new HorizontalLayout(test, test1, test2);
        horizontalLayout.setAlignItems(Alignment.CENTER);
        horizontalLayout.setWidth("80%");
        add(horizontalLayout);
        
        // Center the view content on the page
        setSizeFull();
        // setJustifyContentMode(JustifyContentMode.CENTER);
        setAlignItems(Alignment.CENTER);
    }
}
```

[image: Vaadin result]

hopefully the thing works, when you try it at your end?

[image: CSS playing around 1 (3 Buttons - all 30%)]

(this one has even some extra orange space):

[image: CSS playing around 2 (2 Buttons - both 40%)]

And probably you will also need the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <!-- Project from https://start.vaadin.com/ -->
   <groupId>com.example.application</groupId>
   <artifactId>flowcrmtutorial</artifactId>
   <name>flowcrmtutorial</name>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>

   <properties>
       <java.version>17</java.version>
       <vaadin.version>24.1.4</vaadin.version>
       <selenium.version>4.10.0</selenium.version>
   </properties>

   <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>3.1.0</version>
   </parent>

   <repositories>
       <repository>
           <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
           <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
           <snapshots>
               <enabled>false</enabled>
           </snapshots>
       </repository>
   </repositories>

   <dependencyManagement>
       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
               <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
               <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
               <type>pom</type>
               <scope>import</scope>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>

   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
           <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
           <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
           <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.parttio</groupId>
           <artifactId>line-awesome</artifactId>
           <version>1.1.0</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
           <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
           <scope>runtime</scope>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
           <optional>true</optional>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
           <artifactId>vaadin-testbench-junit5</artifactId>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <build>
       <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <configuration>
                   <jvmArguments>-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5719</jvmArguments>
                   <wait>500</wait>
                   <maxAttempts>240</maxAttempts>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>

           <plugin>
               <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
               <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                       </goals>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

And what I want to achieve is this:

[image: Buttons Horizontally aligned and spread with equal widths]

With the .HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; height: 100vh;">
 <div style="width: 80%;">
     <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
         <button style="width: 30%;">Button 1</button>
         <button style="width: 30%;">Button 2</button>
         <button style="width: 30%;">Button 3</button>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question is difficult to answer for two reasons: 1. your html+css example is almost unreadable because of formatting and irrelevant code. Please format the HTML with proper indentation – that's the most important part of your question and it's really hard to follow right now – and frankly you can remove all the CSS because it is irrelevant. 2. You're not saying what you expect the end result to be. Please provide a drawing or something of what you're trying to achieve – just saying it's "weird" is not helpful when nobody knows what your expectations are.

Comment: Ok. Well I have removed a lot of the auto generated CSS already, but yeah you are right. I will try to remove it some more. My thinking was that someone can just copy paste the code to his computer and reproduce the error. 

I do not know how to draw the result. So I would like the result to be centered. So that left and right margin will be equal. So the purple spacing on the image will be gone. 

I will rewrite the question :) thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I have tried copy-pasting the code, but even this was too little. I will have to rewrite the question just for Vaadin. I though I could get some insight by checking the CSS. Should I delete this question and write a new one? or edit this one?

Comment: If you don't know what the problem is, you probably don't know what the relevant parts of the generated HTML/CSS is either, so you'd be better off 1. posting the code you've actually written (assuming that's Java, then Java), and describing and ideally drawing (with like MS Paint or something) what kind of layout you want to achieve. You can edit this question or delete this and create a new one, doesn't matter much.

Comment: @Rolf I have added a new picture. So basically I would like to get rid of the purple square or rectangle to be exact. I added some annotations with MS Paint. And I added the Java code instead of the generated HTML. So I would like the buttons to be centered and spread equally. Oh I know. I can show that with my own CSS and HTML. Be right back :)

Comment: Ok. Now I have also added a screen shot of what I would like to achieve :) now it might be ok :) let me know if I would need to add anything else :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the empty (or purple, as shown by the browser's inspector) area in the layout is that its contents are left-aligned (the default) rather than horizontally centered.

As shown in the documentation
(https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/horizontal-layout#horizontal-alignment), this is configured with `setJustifyContentMode(JustifyContentMode.CENTER)`.

(The API for setting horizontal and vertical alignment in HorizontalLayout and VerticalLayout are "orthogonal" to each other, because it follows the FlexBox model that works the same way. What I mean by this is that in HorizontalLayout, vertical alignment is set with `setAlignItems` and the horizontal alignment is called "justification" and set with `setJustifyContentMode`, whereas in VerticalLayout it's the other way around. The rationale behind this is that "justification" denotes the layout's "main" or "directional" axis, while "alignment" denotes the "cross axis" that goes "across" the directional axis.)